# for if loop to categorize under condition

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I am pretty new to python and used to use R. For this matter, I would use as.factor and categorize based on the number.

Earlier I was trying to use replace and .loc function in order to give a new category value in a new column according to the condition but it would run only to fail at what I wanted to do.

Eventually I created the following, very simple function:

```
g['Category'] = ""

for i in g['NumFloorsGroup']:
    if i == '0-9' or i == '10-19':
        g['Category'] = 'LowFl'
    elif i == '50~':
        g['Category'] = 'HighFl'
    else:
        g['Category'] = 'NormalFl'
```

When I run the function though, it only returns the 'LowFl' and doesn't correct the other parts. I feel like I am missing something.

the data info is as follows:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 596 entries, 128 to 595
Data columns (total 4 columns):
YearBuilt         596 non-null int64
NumFloorsGroup    596 non-null category
Count             596 non-null int64
Category          596 non-null object
dtypes: category(1), int64(2), object(1)
```

Any comment will be helpful!

```
bins = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, np.inf]
labels = ['0-9', '10-19', '20-29', '30-39', '40-49', '50~']
copy = original_data.copy()
copy['NumFloorsGroup'] = pd.cut(copy['NumFloors'], bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)

g = (copy.groupby(['YearBuilt', 'NumFloorsGroup'])['YearBuilt']
        .count()
        .reset_index(name="Count")
                 .sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False))
```

And the parts that only returns LowFl

```
g['Category'] = ""

for i in g['NumFloorsGroup']:
    if i == '0-9' or i == '10-19':
        g['Category'] = 'LowFl'
    elif i == '50~':
        g['Category'] = 'HighFl'
    else:
        g['Category'] = 'NormalFl'
```

This returns All the Category as LowFl

```
    YearBuilt   NumFloorsGroup  Count   Category
128 1920    0-9 90956   LowFl
171 1930    0-9 76659   LowFl
144 1925    0-9 70387   LowFl
237 1950    0-9 47237   LowFl
91  1910    0-9 46384   LowFl
```

Comment: How is created `NumFloorsGroup` column?

Comment: I used pd.cut with bins and labels based on another column called number of floors @jezrael

Comment: Thanks, is possible see it? I think the best is change it, give me some time for solution.

Comment: I am not sure how to share the entire data, but I will add up what I did in the post. Thank you! @jezrael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest change [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) function with new bins and new labels, because the best is avoid loops in pandas, because slow if exist some vectorized function(s):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Floors':[0,1,10,19,20,25,40, 70]})

bins = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, np.inf]
labels = ['0-9', '10-19', '20-29', '30-39', '40-49', '50~']

df['NumFloorsGroup'] = pd.cut(df['Floors'], 
                              bins=bins, 
                              labels=labels,
                              include_lowest=True)

df['Category'] = pd.cut(df['Floors'], 
                        bins=[0, 19, 50, np.inf], 
                        labels=['LowFl','NormalFl','HighFl'],
                        include_lowest=True)

print (df)
   Floors NumFloorsGroup  Category
0       0            0-9     LowFl
1       1            0-9     LowFl
2      10            0-9     LowFl
3      19          10-19     LowFl
4      20          10-19  NormalFl
5      25          20-29  NormalFl
6      40          30-39  NormalFl
7      70            50~    HighFl
```

Or use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictinary with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace values not in dict (`NaN`s) by `NormalFl`:

```
d = { "0-9": 'LowFl',  "10-19": 'LowFl',"50+": 'HighFl'}
df['Category']  = df['NumFloorsGroup'].map(d).fillna('NormalFl')
```

Comment: Oh, I should have just used the pd cut for this part too! I guess my thought process was too complicated. Thank you!

Comment: @tmhs - Glad can help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
d = {
  "0-9": 'LowFl',
  "10-19": 'LowFl',
  "10-19": '50~',
}
g['NumFloorsGroup'].map(lambda key: d.get(key, 'NormalFl'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your solution isn't working is that you are not iterating over the dataframe. Therefore to correct your solution, instead of directly assigning it to the column, append the values in a list and then, later on, assign the list to the dataframe.

```
category = []
for i in g['NumFloorsGroup']:
    if i == '0-9' or i == '10-19':
        category.append('LowFl')
    elif i == '50~':
        category.append('HighFl')
    else:
        category.append('NormalFl')

g.assign(category = category)
```

Comment: Ah, this is why I always have to create the list and append them. Thanks, I will never forget this after spending so much time wondering why it doesn't work.